# Visual Studio: Custom Configuration and Publish settings

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, publish

I am working on a Winforms application for my company.  I have two publishing locations, one for test .exe's to be published to, and one for release versions.

Rather than editing the publishing folder location and update location for the build each time I swap, is it possible to set up Visual Studio to alter them based on the selected Configuration?  (Debug, Release, etc)

In addition, are there events that fire when certain actions are taken in Visual Studio?  If so, how can I catch them and cause other code to run?  EG automatically send an email when a build is published.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently hit this problem and have come up with a solution using Visual Studio add-ins (vspackage).

My system uses desktop WPF forms, so the Web Deploy options are not applicable.

In the vspackage I request notification on IVsUpdateSolutionEvents2 events and handle the OnActiveProjectCfgChange event. This is fired for every project in the solution (which is not ideal), but the other events are never fired.
I change the following project properties dynamically depending on configuration selected:
AssemblyName
Product
PublishUrl

The AssemblyName and Product changes are required to allow side-by-side ClickOnce deployment on the same desktop. (It came a quite a shock to find out that ClickOnce requires a unique assembly name even though the test and live programs are deployed from different folders on our server.)

n.b. I use configuration-dependent compile time Defines to switch database connection strings. This removes the security hole that occurs when using a config.exe file at run time.